# Set timeout on wp_remote_post()

Tags: remote

I am trying to use `wp_remote_post()` like this:

```
wp_remote_post( $url, array( 'blocking' => false, 'timeout' => 0.1 ) );
```

The problem is that it seems to always force the timeout to 1s.
I don't even want to wait for 1s, I just want the remote post to start and immediately go back to my the calling function. ( I have also tried setting `timeout => 0` but it always takes 1s to return.)

How can I skip this minimum of 1s?

Comment: try, like in `wp_cron`, `'timeout'   => 0.01,`

Answer (score 1):

For cURL, a minimum of 1 second applies, as DNS resolution operates at second-resolution only.
See more in wp-includes/class-request.php function request()

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is the **maximal** not minimal time the functions waits for an answer. So, if the answers comes before the timeout, the function returns the value.

> The argument 'timeout' allows for setting the time in seconds, before the connection is dropped and an error is returned.

source: https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API#Other_Arguments

Also: The timeout has to be an integer, not a float.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word my question clearly enough; I know the `timeout` is the maximum time, but the value that I can set for this option has a minimum of 1 second -- I cannot set it lower than 1 second. "The timeout is the maximal not minimal time the functions waits for an answer. So, if the answers comes before the timeout, the function returns the value." The thing is, I don't want to 'wait for an answer'. I want it to just go to this URL and then let me continue with whatever I want to do. That is the point of using a **non-blocking** remote post.

Comment: So you don't want to change the timeout, you want to make an asynchronous request. That's not built-in in WordPress, you have to work with external libraries like https://icicle.io/ or https://reactphp.org/

Comment: The timeout is float, but it just cannot be less than 1 sec.